# Python 3 - assignments within a loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, variable-assignment

So, I have a large number of arrays that I need a mean value for. To try and simplify I'm attempting to use a for-loop, but I'm not sure if this is possible or if it is, how I can name the left-hand of the assignment line. I've tried:

```
for data in data_list:
    data + _mean = np.mean(data)
```

This gives a syntax error; can't assign to operator. I feel like that's a lame try, but I'm very new to coding and I'm not sure what I can do on the left-hand side to make each assignment have a unique name.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Append the values to a list.

Answer (score 2):

Don't try to give each value a unique name, put them in a list. You can use a list comprehension for this.

```
means = [np.mean(data) for data in data_list]
```

Comment: I didn't know I could use 'for data in data_list' outside of a loop statement - thanks! that makes next step easier as well.

Comment: Look up Python list comprehensions, they're very powerful and common in Python code.